# Xcode beginner - compiling issue

Tags: c, xcode

I am very new to the Xcode environment. I would like to compile some .c and .cpp files. So I created a project with the generic c++ plugin (is it the right choice?). It builds the file with success, but I have no result displaying, even for the "hello world" printf file. Can anyone help? If someone could reccomend some good tutorial, that would be great!

Here is my example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We need code... we need a specific question... we need something.

Comment: yep, it's just a test code :-)#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

    printf("Hello World");
}

Comment: You say it builds and there is no result. Did you actually try running it?

Comment: In fact, I push the run button, then the outbut is "build succeeded", but in the console, nothing such as a result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a `Command Line Tool` project, not Generic C++ Plugin.

Once you do that, your output will show up in the console window in xcode.